# Format data to fit GraphQL schema

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am using DynamoDB as my database. Since it's a NoSQL database, I store data in a certain way that doesn't fit the way I want to receive the data from GraphQL. I am fairly new to everything around GraphQL, Apollo and DynamoDB.

If we set those schema as an exemple:

```
type App: { 
  activities: [Activity] 
}

type Activity: { 
  name: String!
  desc: String
}

type Query {
  activity(name: String!): Activity
}
```

My goal for my `activity` query is to get the activity going by the name provided. To get easy access, I store it this way in DynamoDB.

```
{ 
  activities: {
    exempleName: {
      desc: 'exempleDesc'
    }
  }
}
```

This way, I can easily find it by getting `activity.exempleName`, except now I get an object like this:

```
{ 
  desc:'exempleDesc'
}
```

when I need this to fit my schema:

```
{ 
  name:'exempleName'
  desc:'exempleDesc'
}
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? Keep in mind that it must be reused for many objects with different field names.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement dynamic fields in GraphQL?

Comment: I was more asking if anything like this existed. I will definitely check it out and update. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could clarify your question. At least to me, it's not very clear what you're asking. In both code blocks, you've got what looks like properties on an array. The syntax in either code block is not valid js, JSON or SDL. Maybe providing sample data from your database **and** your desired GraphQL schema would clarify what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: This should be better.